# can I change file system for one directory in partition?

Tags: filesystems

I need to perform `cramfs` file system on one file or directory in one partition to make the file read only. I don't want to make it read only by change mode command but I want to  perform different file system to the file.

Answer (score 1):

Create an image file, then mount it with `-o loop` parameter.
And i recommend to not use `cramfs`, because `squashfs` is much better in every respect.